# Can I bypass solenoid clutch switch by grounding the pin directly with a wire to the chassis/frame?

Tags: motorcycle, wiring, ignition-switch, switches, solenoid

My solenoid switch has 4 pin for an Honda motorbike. One of the primary pin to be energized for the solenoid to click is the clutch switch.
My question is: can I connect the pin with a wire that i'm going to connect directly to the ground (chassis/frame) of the motorbike? 
This is the clutch diagram: https://pasteboard.co/HvLasSh.png 
The clutch passes from a diode that i want to skip/bypass
Thanks, regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does depend how it is wired, it can be the clutch switch grounds or earths the pin or it feeds it with a supply, make sure you know which it does as you could blow a fuse or start a fire...

You need to work out what is happening - a multimeter can help or consult the wiring diagram.

Comment: Hi Mike, this is the diagram for the clutch switch: https://pasteboard.co/HvLasSh.png , it passes trough a diode which I want to completely bypass, and always show as a closed circuit.

Comment: Add relevant info, diagrams etc to the original question - people don’t trawl through comments building your question...

Comment: Read the diagram, follow the wires and work out the function. The image you have posted is a small, barely legible, section of the complete diagram...

Comment: Hi Mike, sure, i will, this diagram is taken from a very bad quality black and white scanned old service manual of Honda XL Degree 250 found on the net, that's why i'm having trouble even to read the letter for the colors.

Comment: The go with the multi-meter, operate the switches and see what happens where...

Comment: Hi Mike, i tested with the multi-meter the solenoid and find out the configuration and which pin are the primary with longer resistance and the secondary one with shorter resistance, i also tested the solenoid "click" by connecting the clutch pin to one side of the battery and the "starter push button pin" to the other side and it works well as it clicks, now i would like to know how to replicate this with the wiring. I would like to connect the clutch pin with a wire (Perhaps with an inline fuse holder) directly to ground. Would that work in your opinion?